# Track last user login with ASP MVC Identity 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

What´s the best place to track the last login date for user? My web app supports cookie authentication, external authentication by Google / Facebook and good old username / password auth. 
So it probably needs to be done somewhere deep in the system. First

```
AccountController.SignInAsync
```

looked like a good idea, but it doesnt seem to be called on cookie authentication.
Any ideas?

Comment: Not too sure if a datetime is stored in the UserManager . I generally have a system table that i add basic tracking into.

Comment: Did you find an answer?